# Infinite loop with file handling and istringstreams

Tags: c++, fstream, istringstream

I have a file containing data in the following form:

```
ballcolor 10
bgcolor 5
[...]
```

Which I'm trying to read via the following:

```
void read (const char *filename)
{
    ifstream prefsfile (filename);
    if (prefsfile.is_open ())
    {
        char prefsline [BUFSIZE], prefname [BUFSIZE];
        unsigned int value;

        while (! prefsfile.eof ())
        {
            prefsfile.getline (prefsline, BUFSIZE);

            istringstream iss (prefsline);
            iss >> prefname >> value;
            if (! (iss.fail () || prefsfile.fail ()))
            {
                if (! strcmpi (prefname, PREFSTR_PAD_COLOR) && value <= BACKGROUND_MAX)
                {
                    color.pad = value << 4;
                }
                else if (! strcmpi (prefname, PREFSTR_BALL_COLOR) && value <= FOREGROUND_MAX)
                {
                    color.ball = value;
                }
                else if (! strcmpi (prefname, PREFSTR_FOREGROUND_COLOR) && value <= FOREGROUND_MAX)
                {
                    color.foreground = value;
                }
                else if (! strcmpi (prefname, PREFSTR_BACKGROUND_COLOR) && value <= BACKGROUND_MAX)
                {
                    color.background = value << 4;
                    color.ball |= color.background;
                }
            }
        }
        prefsfile.close ();
    }
}
```

If I give it a file that exactly conforms to the format shown above, it works well. However, if the file doesn't conform, or if the length of each line is larger than `BUFSIZE(=30)`, it goes in an infinite loop.

How do I resolve the problem?

Comment: If prefsline is BUFSIZE in length, your getline statement should be `prefsfile.getline (prefsline, BUFSIZE);` otherwise you are potentially writing beyond the end of your buffer.

Comment: @TomFenech, as I stated above `BUFSIZE` is 30; anyway editing to correct it.

Comment: `while (! prefsfile.eof ())` is wrong. Who taught you to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for `! prefsfile.eof ()` but if you checked for the more generic `prefsfile.good()` your loop  should break if the line is longer than `BUFSIZE`.

[The getline reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) explains when the failbit is set. In particular, if the delimiter is not found by the time `BUFSIZE` characters have been read from the input.

I would read the file like this:

```
void read (const char *filename)
{
    ifstream prefsfile (filename);
    if (prefsfile.is_open ())
    {
        char prefsline [BUFSIZE], prefname [BUFSIZE];
        unsigned int value;

        while (prefsfile.getline(prefsline, BUFSIZE))
        {                        
            if (prefsfile.eof()) {
                break;
            }

            istringstream iss (prefsline);
            iss >> prefname >> value;
            cout << prefname << " " << value << "\n";
        }
        prefsfile.close ();
    }
}
```

If the line is too long, the `while` loop condition will evaluate to false.

**Test 1** - long line breaks the loop

```
ballcolor 10
really really long line that is over 30 characters
bgcolor 5
```

output:

```
ballcolor 10
```

**Test 2** - shorter lines

```
ballcolor 10
bgcolor 5
```

output:

```
ballcolor 10
bgcolor 5
```